# azerty on windows server 2008 core

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I'm running a Windows Server 2008 R2 core and I would like to change the keyboard setting from qwerty to azerty.

How can I do that?

Thanks,

KiTe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `control intl.cpl`, this starts a GUI tool for setting international keyboards etc.